# Can i have the following route in ASP.NET MVC :: http://whatever/controller/action.format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

is it possible to add a `dot format / .format` to the end of any route in ASP.NET MVC .. with a default being html or something?

and of course the `.format` is an optional value.

sample routes:-

```
http://whatever/controller/action.format
http://whatever/controller/action
```

those goto the same action method.

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the only clean way to do this would be with two route definitions:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}.{format}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", format = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default2",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Make sure you maintain the same order in your route definition list as the "Default2" route will override the "Default" route in all cases if placed before it.